# How to create component or dynamic zone like Strapi CMS in Directus CMS

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, directus

We can create group of fields used as component in Strapi or dynamic zone, how can we create the same in Directus CMS

I have tried Directus's group field but it won't work like Strapi component.

Answer (score 0):

There's a field called M2A. This is basically what strapi dynamic zone is.